# How to append text to div using ID in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Here i am using function to print the values to div with `id="mylist"`.i am using the loop and calling the `printList()` function with the value and i am printing the value in `printList()` but its not working.how can i do this?

```
<div id="mylist"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
 function coucity(){
   for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     printList(i);
    }
 }

 function printList(city){
  var writecity = document.write(city);
  document.getElementById("mylist").append(writecity);
 }
```

and also i want to add delay for printing the values.

Comment: Where did you invoked `coucity()`?

Comment: i am calling coucity() on body load.

Comment: Also, on your line `document.getElementById("myDIV").append(writecity);` you should have the same name of the div id (in your example it's "mylist" but on your code it's "myDIV". Makes sure they match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var writecity = document.createTextNode(city);
document.getElementById("mylist").appendChild(writecity);
```

This should work.

Basically, you only append other DOM Node (as child) to DOM Nodes. so you use `document.createTextNode()` to create node and `document.appendChild()` to add it as a child to existing node.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is `document.write` returns nothing, also using it is not recommended. Secondly dom does not have function `append`, instead it is `appendChild`.

Try `document.createTextNode` and `appendChild`:

```js
function coucity() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    printList(i);
  }
}

function printList(i) {
  document.getElementById("mylist").appendChild(document.createTextNode(i));
}
```

```html
<body onload="coucity();">
  <div id="mylist"></div>
</body>
```

You may also try `innerHTML`:

```js
function coucity() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    printList(i);
  }
}

function printList(i) {
  document.getElementById("mylist").innerHTML += i;
}
```

```html
<body onload="coucity();">
  <div id="mylist"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things wrong with your code, all of which can easily be found out by checking the JavaScript console.

1. You don't call `coucity` anywhere (but a comment shows that is is called from elsewhere, so that shouldn't be the problem)
2. `document.write` should be `document.createTextNode`
3. `getElementById("myDIV")` does not find the div with id `mylist`
4. `append` should be `appendChild`
5. and finally, if you correct all these errors, it only outputs the digits 0 through 9 instead of cities.

I can't help you with the last one, but with the other errors corrected, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/0jn7xzzb/2/) is the result.

```javascript
function coucity(){
   for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     printList(i);
    }
}

function printList(city){
  var writecity = document.createTextNode(city);
  document.getElementById("mylist").appendChild(writecity);
}

coucity();
```

To add a delay, there are several methods available. Which would be best depends on your needs. In this simple case, you can even write

```
function coucity(){
   for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     setTimeout(printList, i*1000, i);
    }
}
```

See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/0jn7xzzb/3/).

Answer (score 0):

An example of [appending](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) a [text node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode) to a `div`, [referenced by id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById), with a [delay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout).

```js
function appendDelayedTextNode(element, text, delayMs) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
    }, delayMs);
}

var mylist = document.getElementById('mylist');

appendDelayedTextNode(mylist, 'one', 1000);
appendDelayedTextNode(mylist, 'two', 2000);
appendDelayedTextNode(mylist, 'three', 3000);
```

```html
<div id="mylist"></div>
```